# Ignoring content diffs on certain parts of pages with difflib & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, difflib

The following code is working well to pull out *content-only* changes to a [certain type of page](https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/reference.nsf/links/02092016062645AM):

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = 'https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/reference.nsf/links/02092016062645AM'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()  # get response as list of lines

#url2 = 'https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/reference.nsf/links/02092016055519AM'
url2 = 'file:///Users/Pyderman/repos/02092016062645AM-modified.html'
response2 = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
content2 = response2.read()  # get response as list of lines
import difflib
d = difflib.Differ()

diffed = d.compare(content, content)
#print('\n'.join(diffed))

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
soup2= bs4.BeautifulSoup(content2, "lxml")
diff = d.compare(list(soup.stripped_strings), list(soup2.stripped_strings))
changes = [change for change in diff if change.startswith('-') or  change.startswith('+')]
for change in changes:
    print change
#print('\n'.join(diff))
```

This pages is essentially a document, and as such, I am only interested in detecting diffs to the parts of the page **above the footer** and **below the menus** at the top. I was expecting there to be rarely changes to the footer or the menus on a page like this, but re-running the diff a few days later showed that subtle changes had been made:

```
- Potential Entitlement
- Social Security Statement
- American Indians and Alaska Natives
+ American Indians/Alaska Natives
- Asian Americans and Pacific Islanders
+ Asian Americans/Pacific Islanders
- Self-employed
+ Self-Employed
- Awards
+ Digital Government Strategy
+ Open Government
- Podcasts
- Webinars
- Digital Government Strategy
```

Given that I have gone the **BeautifulSoup** route of parsing the whole page (rather than, say parsing just sections of it with **lxml**), am I restricted here? Will I need to go back and break the page into sections (or just section `//div[@class = 'grid']`) before running it through **difflib**?